# Regular Expression PHP Help with if not equal to

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use regular expressions to make my inventory upload script a little better.

I sell clothing and accessories. In my inventory file I have a field called ProductDepartment which is a combination of gender/item type. I have a MySQL table for gender with the following values:

```
Mens = 1
Womens = 2
Unisex = 3
```

Departments in the uploaded file look like the following, for example.

```
Mens Outerwear
Mens Watches
Womens Jeans
Headphones
```

So basically Im trying to make a statment that goes, if $ProductDept contains Mens, set $gender_id = 1, if $ProductDept contains Womens, set $gender_id = 2, if $ProductDept does not contain either, set $gender_id = 3

And I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the 3rd if statement correctly. Here's what I have.

```
if(preg_match('/Mens/g', $ProductDept)) {
    $gender_id = '1';
}

if(preg_match('/Womens/g', $ProductDept)) {
    $gender_id = '2';
}

if( != preg_match('/Mens|Womens/g', $ProductDept)) {
    $gender_id = '3';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `!=` to `!`:

```
if (!preg_match('/Mens|Womens/g', $ProductDept)) { ... }
```

You could also rewrite it using elseif as follows:

```
if (preg_match('/Womens/g', $ProductDept)) {
    $gender_id = '2';
} elseif (preg_match('/Mens/g', $ProductDept)) {
    $gender_id = '1';
} else {
    $gender_id = '3';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do :

```
if(preg_match('/Womens/', $ProductDept)) {
  $gender_id = '2';
} elseif(preg_match('/Mens/', $ProductDept)) {
  $gender_id = '1';
} else {
  $gender_id = '3';
}
```